# Use 2x4 Studs 90 Degrees from Normal

Tags: framing

I'm looking to put up some drywall in front of a concrete wall in my basement. Just for hanging things on, and to make the space nicer.

There are some pipes that run horizontal along the top of the concrete wall, about 2" away from it. Can I just turn my 2x4's 90 degrees and attach them to the wall that way? That's the only way they'd fit between the pipes and the concrete wall. I don't need the drywall to go all the way up to the ceiling, I'm fine with leaving it short to allow for the pipes.

Thanks for any help.

- Jason

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can. Just be aware that they won't be as rigid in the case that you hang heavy objects on them, such as cabinetry. You might consider putting one or two fasteners into the concrete through each stud, leaving an air space behind the stud. (You don't want untreated lumber in contact with masonry.)

Alternatively, built your wall  as you normally would and notch those studs around the pipe at the top. Use a 2x2 for a top plate behind the pipe. This will leave you with more robust framing and the ability to install full-size outlet boxes, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much. How do I leave an air space, is there some sort of spacer that I'd use? I thought I should use pressure-treated 2x4's, just in case.

Comment: Either stop screwing early or slip a spacer block behind.

Comment: +1 for thinking about electrical boxes too...